# PHP printing unquoted characters

Tags: php, printing

In creating a parameters for a function I accidentally found that you could use unquoted characters. Is this behavior normal? should I expect to keep using it in the long run?

I'm using this:

```
>php -version
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0 Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

On this:

```
echo _;  // outputs _
echo a;  // outputs a. And so forth from a-z and A-Z
echo /;  // signals error
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that PHP is trying to regard the `_` and `a` as the names of some  constants, and when it does not find them, it just assumes that they are strings containing these characters. However, `/`is not an allowed symbol for a constant name, which gives you an error. I'd suggest yanking up the error reporting level so that PHP would give you notices on such things.